# How to get Continuous date in Presto with start date in one column and end date in another column

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, presto

The below is how the Raw table looks like in presto

[image: Input Table]

I would like to create a new table where for each Item ID the continuous dates should have a start date and end date wherever it is continuous in presto

The below is how the sample table will look like

[image: Output Table]

Comment: Are you using Hive or Presto?  They are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  The simplest method is to subtract a sequence to get a constant date -- and then aggregate:

```
select id, min(datefield), max(datefield)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by datefield) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, (datefield - seqnum * interval '1 day');
```

Window function differ by databases.  The logic is the same, but the syntax for subtracting `seqnum` days from `datefield` may vary.

Comment: Can you please help me with an understanding of why you are using (datefield - seqnum * interval '1 day') in group by and help with an example on how it is calculated

Comment: @rpunk21 . . . Run the code `select t.*, (datefield - seqnum * interval '1 day') from t order by id, datefield` and you should be able to see for yourself.